How to do fuzzy matching with large data file
I have two files. One has 1 million rows (30 MB) and the other has 30 million rows (9 GB). I'd love to do fuzzy matching based on companyname_std column and disambig_assignee_organization_std column respectively. As these files contain too many rows, running time is very long. I'd love to fasten the process. So, I use multiprocessing. However, my multiprocessing seems running forever (run a long time that I have to kill it even for sample files). Does anyone know the reason? Thanks. My code (use single process) is:
import pandas as pd
from rapidfuzz import process
from tqdm import tqdm
import re
import multiprocessing as mp

# Function to standardize the organization names
def standardize_text(text):
    if pd.isnull(text):
        return ''
    # Convert to lowercase
    text = text.lower()
    # Remove special characters
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text)
    # Remove extra spaces
    text = ' '.join(text.split())
    return text

def match_and_merge(rows):
    results = []
    for row in rows:
        match = process.extract(row['companyname_std'], assignee_orgs_std, limit=1)
        if match and match[0][1] > 90:
            matched_org = df1_csv[df1_csv['disambig_assignee_organization_std'] == match[0][0]].iloc[0]
            row_series = pd.Series(row)
            merged_row = pd.concat([row_series, matched_org], axis=0)
            results.append(merged_row.tolist() + [1])
        else:
            row_series = pd.Series(row)
            empty_series = pd.Series([None] * len(df1_csv.columns), index=df1_csv.columns)
            merged_row = pd.concat([row_series, empty_series], axis=0)
            results.append(merged_row.tolist() + [0])
    return results

# Paths to the CSV files
csv_file1 = "g_patent.csv"
csv_file2 = "1. pitchbook_company.csv"
output_file = "final_patent_sample.csv"

# Load data from CSV files
df1_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_file1, nrows=1000)
df2_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_file2, nrows=1000)

# Standardize the organization names
df1_csv['disambig_assignee_organization_std'] = df1_csv['disambig_assignee_organization'].apply(standardize_text)
df2_csv['companyname_std'] = df2_csv['companyname'].apply(standardize_text)

# Extract the standardized column to match on
assignee_orgs_std = df1_csv['disambig_assignee_organization_std'].tolist()

# Initialize an empty DataFrame for matched results or load the last saved batch
try:
    matched_df = pd.read_csv(output_file)
    start_index = matched_df.shape[0]  # Start from the next unsaved batch
    print(f"Resuming from index: {start_index}")
except FileNotFoundError:
    matched_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df2_csv.columns.tolist() + df1_csv.columns.tolist() + ['merge_flag'])
    start_index = 0
    print("No previous saved file found, starting from the beginning.")

# Resume from the last saved point
df2_csv = df2_csv[start_index:]
batch_size = 100 
header_written = False
output_file = "final_patent_sample.csv"
for i in tqdm(range(0, df2_csv.shape[0], batch_size)):
    batch = df2_csv.iloc[i:i + batch_size].to_dict(orient='records')
    results = match_and_merge(batch)
    batch_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=matched_df.columns)
    batch_df.to_csv(output_file, mode='a', index=False, header=not header_written)
    header_written = True 

Using multiprocessing:
with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as pool:
    batch_generator = (df2_csv.iloc[i:i + batch_size].to_dict(orient='records')
                       for i in range(0, df2_csv.shape[0], batch_size))
    for results in pool.imap(match_and_merge, batch_generator):
        batch_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=matched_df.columns)
        batch_df.to_csv(output_file, mode='a', index=False, header=not header_written)
        header_written = True


Instead of just throwing large files at a solution, you're generally better off starting with smaller files and testing and refining your solution and then scaling up. It is of course true that some solutions only start to pay off at larger sizes, so they shouldn't be trivially small, but a solution that completes in a couple of seconds should already show improvements and certainly work without issues. Have you tested with smaller data sizes? Was the multiprocessing solution any faster?

I think you should try cdist before multiprocessing. Please provide a realistic sample of CSVs if you need more information.
